# postgres sql определить права доступа

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
GRANT SELECT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "one" TO back_office_user;

GRANT INSERT ALL ON Table1,Table3,Table5 TO back_office_user;
```

пытаюсь выдать права, первая строчка работает вторая нет, все вроде по докам

Comment: Вы уверены?  У меня не работает ни первая, ни вторая.  `ALL` лишнее, КМК.

Comment: Если убрать ALL то даже не запускается, говорит синаксис эрор

Comment: по вот этой схеме делал https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-grant.html

Comment: Следите внимательнее за скобками и ИЛИ. Либо `grant select on ` либо `grant all on`